# Update multiples rows with different ID at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

is it possible to do something like this?

```
update table set field ='text' where ID=1 and ID=3 and ID=5
```

I executed it but no row is updated.

Comment: The ANDs make it want all the rows to have all those values simultaneously, which is clearly impossible. Use OR, either than or use an IN clause (which is just a short-hand for lots of ORs). You want the ID to be "one from any of those" not "all of those at the same time". Dont forget that SQL evaluates each row individually and applies the entire Where clause to each row in turn. When you write your queries try to keep this in mind and consider how the code would affect one individual row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `IN` rather than `AND` :

```
update table set field ='text' where ID IN (1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Great! this is it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN after WHERE like below,

```
update table set field ='text' where ID in (1, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass collection of some data from sql you can use IN key word

```
update table set field ='text' where ID in (1, 2,3,4,5,6,7);
```